# Transfer Learning on few data / personalized general model keras

Tags: networking, keras, model, transfer-learning

I have a problem with my neural network. I trained it for general data, and works quite good. But now I would like improve the network with new data personalized.

I try to explain.. My model is general, and I use it for one individual X. But with the time I will receive more data from X and I would like to improve the general model for X. For example each time I receive 3 new datas can I re fit with only 1 epoch?

Or should I use dynamical clustering (If is possible) and put it in input of my network?

I really don't know what should do and need help.. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of model you have, but in general, you can train a model with your data, then save the model using `model.save` which saves everything (architecture, optimizer status, weights and biases etc).

```
# saving the model in tensorflow format
model.save('./MyModel_tf',save_format='tf')
```

When you have new data, you can load the model using `tf.keras.model.load_model`, and retrain it to update the parameters. If your model is not taking much time, adding the new data to the existing training folder would be better. You could also use some data augmentation to improve the performance.

```
# loading the saved model
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./MyModel_tf')

# retraining the model
loaded_model.fit(x_new_data, y_new_data, epochs = 10, validation_data = (x_test,y_test),verbose=1)
```

You can check [this example](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Keras_model_Continue_training_2.ipynb) for retraining the model where you left. You can update the some hyper parameters and run the reloaded model to improve the performance. Hope it helps!

Comment: First thanks for answer.

But my problem is more about the quantity of data, because I will receive the data 1 by 1 and I would like to train for each new data. But if it's not enough maybe it will overfit my new data?

Is it possible to train only on 1 data? How much epochs should I do?

Sorry I explain a bit bad, but it's quite hard to explain...

Comment: Based on your explanation, I think "Online Machine Learning Technique" is the way to go. Please check [this resource](https://medium.com/value-stream-design/online-machine-learning-515556ff72c5). Please do some more in-depth study to know better about that technique. Thanks